# Slow motion control in windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, media-player, windows-phone

I want to add the slow motion functions to a windows phone 8 app to control the speed of the player to 1/2 and 1/4 speed of the default speed of the player in xaml/ c#.
can any one give me an idea how to do it please?

Comment: As it's not part of the built-in system APIs, you will have to write a media player yourself.